# Building multiple parts of formula strings from different inputs in R

Tags: r

I have been building a function that creates more advanced formula snippets using simple formula code. For example, a user may write:
$$Given\ dependent\ variable\ Y,\ and\ indepdentent\ variables\ X\  and \ U$$
$$Argument\ 1:\ Y_t = \alpha_t +  X_t,\ where\ X_t\ \to\  X_t + \sum_{i = -k}^k \Delta X_{t-i}$$
$$Argument\ 2: \ =U_t ,\ where\ U_t \to\ +\sum_{I = 1}^k U_{t-i} $$

in R: `y ~ 1 + x` becomes `y ~ 1 + x + L(diff(x),-k:k)` and

in R: `~ u` becomes `L(u,1:k)`

I have built the following but am curious for feedback as **(1)** the code itself feels lengthy and **(2)** it is not super intuitive for a user to start Argument 2 with a `~`.

```
buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat)
#[1] "y ~ 1 + x + L(diff(x),-k:k)"

buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x + u + z, data = dat)
#[1] "y ~ 1 + x + u + z + L(diff(x),-k:k) + L(diff(u),-k:k) + L(diff(z),-k:k)"

buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat, Arg2 = ~ u) 
#[1] "y ~ 1 + x + L(diff(x),-k:k) + L(u,1:k)"

buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat, Arg2 = ~ u + z) 
#[1] "y ~ 1 + x + L(diff(x),-k:k) + L(u,1:k) + L(z,1:k)"

buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat, Arg2 = ~u) 
#[1] "y ~ 1 + x + L(diff(x),-k:k) + L(u,1:k)"

buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat, Arg2 = u + z)
#Error in ... :  
#  object 'u' not found

buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat, Arg2 = u + z)
#Error in ... : 
#  object 'u' not found
```

**(3)** I would also be appreciative if someone would recommend how to catch this error and warn the user to add a `~` in `Arg2`.

**Function Code**

```
# generate data
dat <- cbind(y = rnorm(30), x = rnorm(30), u = rnorm(30), z = rnorm(30))
# function
buildFormula <- function(Arg1, data, Arg2 = NULL){
  ff <- Arg1
  all_names <- dimnames(attr(terms(ff), "factors"))
  y_names <- all_names[[1]][!(all_names[[1]] %in% all_names[[2]])]
  x_names <- all_names[[2]][all_names[[2]] %in% colnames(data)]
  ff_LHS <- y_names
  # building the right hand side ( ~ X1 + X2 + L(diff(X1),-k:k) + L(diff(X2),-k:k) ) 
  ff_RHS <- paste(c(ifelse(attr(terms(ff), "intercept") == 1, "1", "-1"), # intercept
                    x_names, # independent variables
                    paste0("L(diff(", x_names, "),-k:k)")), # sum of lagged differences of independent variables
                  collapse = " + ")
  # if extra was indicated, add it on but treat it differently (~ + L(X3, 1:k) )
  ff_RHS <- ifelse(is.null(Arg2), ff_RHS, paste0(ff_RHS, " + ", 
                                                   paste0("L(", unlist(strsplit(as.character(Arg2)[-1], " \\+ ")), 
                                                          ",1:k)", 
                                                          collapse = " + ")))
  ff_k <- paste(ff_LHS, "~", ff_RHS)
  ff_k
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1

The function is a bit lengthy indeed. I have some general remarks, but I will hold them off, because I have some suggestions that would fix points 2 and 3.

## 2

The source of the error is because `u + z` is not interpreted as a formula, but rather as the addition of two variables. So when you interact with `Arg2`, an error is thrown. Adding the `~` fixes this, because it is recognized as a formula then.

A workaround for this problem is to combine both parts of the formula into one. This is something other packages in `R` do as well. (`mlogit::mFormula` is one example from the top of my head) The combined formula would look like so: `y ~ x | u + z`. You can then split the RHS at the `|` and do your work on each part of the formula.

## 3

Catching the problem is really quite hard, because any interaction with `Arg2` will trigger the evaluation of `u+z`, which in turn throws an error if `u` or `z` don't exist.

What you can do is use `tryCatch`. This function allows you to evaluate an expression and define a function that is executed if an error or warning is thrown.

```
> tryCatch(is.formula(1+1), error = function(e)stop("bla"))
[1] FALSE
> tryCatch(is.formula(u + z), error = function(e)stop("bla"))
 Error in value[[3L]](cond) : bla 
> tryCatch(is.formula(~u + z), error = function(e)stop("bla"))
[1] TRUE
```

You could add this to the top of your function:

```
if(!tryCatch(is.formula(1+1), 
    error = function(e)FALSE))){
    stop("Arg2 is not a formula, be sure to add \"~\" to the start.")
}
```

## Back to 1

String operations will quickly look very wordy, but that's all fine. You are working with words after all.

You spend 4 lines dissecting the formula for the LHS and the RHS. This can be done a lot more easily by coercing the formula to a string:

```
> as.character(a+b~c+d)
[1] "~"     "a + b" "c + d"
```

Before you do coercion, you should test whether the thing you are coercing is actually what you expect it to be. So add a test to the top of the function:

```
stopifnot(is.formula(Arg1))
```

We still should separate removing the intercept from the rest of the formula. Because we don't want to see `L(diff(-1,-k:k))`. So we test whether `-1` is in the RHS, remove it if it is and at the end, add it back if necessary:

```
  removeIntercept <- grepl("-1", RHS)
  if(removeIntercept){
    splitRHS[[1]] <- splitRHS[[1]][!grepl("-1", splitRHS[[1]])]
  }
```

Putting it back:

```
  if(removeIntercept){
    ff_RHS <- paste("-1 +", ff_RHS)
  }
```

If we run with the suggestion in part 2, about combining the formulae, we can drop `Arg2`. We then split the RHS on `|`. Because we coerced the formula to character, we can do this with `strsplit`. We then want to split the formula for each of the terms. Again with `strsplit`.

The argument `data` is not used, so we can omit it.

Right now we are returning a string, as per the function in OP, but the function is called `buildFormula`, so it would be nice to wrap the output in `as.formula`, so that the name fits the output (or you can rename the function).

The new function would be:

```
buildFormula <- function(formula){
  stopifnot(is.formula(formula))
  
  ffAsChar <- as.character(formula)
  LHS <- ffAsChar[2]
  RHS <- strsplit(ffAsChar[3], "[|]")[[1]]
  
  splitRHS <- strsplit(RHS, "[+]")
  removeIntercept <- grepl("-1", RHS[1])
  if(removeIntercept){
    splitRHS[[1]] <- splitRHS[[1]][!grepl("-1", splitRHS[[1]])]
  }
  
  
  ff_RHS <- paste(splitRHS[[1]], 
                  paste0("L(diff(", 
                         splitRHS[[1]], 
                         "),-k:k)"), 
                  collapse = " + ", 
                  sep = " + ")
  if(length(splitRHS) > 1){
    ff_RHS <- paste0(ff_RHS, "+",
                     paste("L(", splitRHS[[2]], ",1:k)",
                           collapse = " + ")) 
  }
  if(removeIntercept){
    ff_RHS <- paste("-1 +", ff_RHS)
  }
  paste(LHS, "~", ff_RHS)
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
> buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x, data = dat)
[1] "a ~ x + L(diff(x),-k:k)"
> 
> buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x + u + z, data = dat)
[1] "a ~ x  + L(diff(x ),-k:k) +  u  + L(diff( u ),-k:k) +  z + L(diff( z),-k:k)"
> 
> buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x | u, data = dat) 
[1] "a ~ x  + L(diff(x ),-k:k)+L(  u ,1:k)"
> 
> buildFormula(Arg1 = y ~ x | u + z, data = dat) 
[1] "a ~ x  + L(diff(x ),-k:k)+L(  u  ,1:k) + L(  z ,1:k)"
```

Comment: This was a well thought out post that gave me a lot to think about and provided an alternative method and a way to catch given my current setup. I accepted it as an answer, thanks for your time!

Comment: @EvanFriedland You're welcome :) I took a peek at your other question, but sadly I know too little of the method you are implementing to be of any help there.

Comment: I should probably delete that question. Since I got the method to work-- i'll recreate one as a code review post another time. Appreciate you taking a look